# Why does my htaccess not rewrite properly

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having a problem with my htaccess file, and can't figure out if it's my configuration, or something like server cache which is messing with my URLs.

My file is the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]
```

The first rule is to move www to non-www, it works.

The second rule is to move http to https, it also works.

the third rule is to make URL `/anyFile` call `anyFile.php`, but keep a lovely URL.

The problem is that it calls `anyFile.html`, not PHP, and if I remove said HTML file then I get 404.

Yes it works typing anyFile.php in the URL, but I would like to not have .php in the URL.
If it is not obvious enough, it is supposed to work for any file name, not just a single one.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: Adding gibberish on top of my .htaccess does create an internal server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your .htaccess rules with this code:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# single rule for http->https and www removal
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# hide .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I just tried this and the Options -MultiViews part gives the server an internal error (500).
Could that be the problem?
This doesn't work any better than my current without the Options -MultiViews part.

Comment: Yes that could very well be the problem as disabling `MultiViews` is important. Your Apache config may not have allowed you to use `Options` in your .htaccess. Check Apache error.log for reason of 500

Comment: I will contact my host with this problem, I have no doubt the code will work,  logic says it must, so MultiViews must be the problem.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: But... even with `MultiViews` enabled, you should not get a 404 after having _deleted_ `anyFile.html`. (Unless the _resulting request_ is somehow cached server-side?!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm recently learn how to do htaccess too, so I'm still a novice but I would write

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ helloWorld.php [NC]
```

to redirect it to the `helloWorld.php` file.

The `$1` is a get parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify that the rewrite is supposed to rewrite EVERY /something so it calls something.php. It is supposed to be a parameter.

Comment: Oh I realize what was wrong. You have a capital W in your file name. Your regex only checks for lowercase. Use [a-zA-Z0-9#%@&\s\(\)\[\]\-]* instead of [a-z]+     My regex checks for any character.

Comment: Adding both lowercase and uppercase to the rule is a good idea yes, but not center of the problem. the Problem is that it should rewrite to PHP, not HTML.

Comment: The OP is already using the `NC` (`NOCASE`) flag so matches are case-insensitive. `$1` is a _backreference_ to the parenthesised subpattern in the `RewriteRule`, not a "get parameter".